# Post-commit review in Azure DevOps like in Upsource

Tags: azure-devops, upsource

Is this possible to do a post-commit reviews in Azure DevOps like in JetBrains' Upsource? We're thinking about migration to DevOps from other git service and we'd still like to have 2 branches (master/develop) without a need of creating feature branches and pull requests.